# Should tag "parastitic" be changed to "parasite"?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

"parastitic" is not a word. So it shouldn't be a tag [parastitic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parastitic).
I assume this should have been "parasitic"... but, honestly, that's a pretty weird word both to read and to pronounce, at least for me. I'd rather us fix it by going to "parasite".

Comment: sure it is misspelling, just fix it

Comment: I don't seem to have that edit ability to replace tags. How would I do that?

Comment: @MolbOrg I tried editing all the questions that used the tag... that fixes the questions, but the misspelled tag still exists in the tag lists. I think a moderator has to fix this.

Comment: I had in mind to use that http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms as way to solve but rules are a bit more tricky than I thought(idk if it easier at higher rep), so it might need a mod intervention. Also, just matter of preferences might be, but it seems to me that parasitic variant might be better than parasite, even when those questions describe those aliens using the word parasite, but what they are asking for is parasitic behavior and how it goes along with what they ask for.

Comment: Sorry @Oded -- totally missed the "bug" tag when I was looking at this.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - no worries - not expecting mods to police the tag :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody already edited the four questions to change the tag, but the tag with the typo had a wiki so can't be auto-deleted.  I edited to remove the wiki (which was only one sentence anyway), but the editor required that I supply a wiki excerpt in order to make the edit.  So I did that; I *think* the excerpt won't prevent the tag from being auto-purged, but please check back in a couple days and let us know if it's still there.

I also renamed the new tag from "parasite" to "parasites".  Noun tags work better as plurals.

In this case there were only four questions so it didn't matter, but in the future, if we need to rename a tag that's on a lot of questions, it's better to have a moderator do the rename instead of individually editing (and bumping) all the questions.  Only moderators can rename tags.

Comment: Noted. Several of us learned a lot during this particular test. :-)

Comment: Could you do the same thing with [tag:behaviour], or is a synonym more appropriate? Just asking in a comment because it is relevant to this post / a new post would overlap greatly.

Comment: @Zxyrra behaviour and what other tag?

Comment: @MonicaCellio "behavior" as in the American spelling --- I don't have the rep to propose a synonym even if it's just for spelling. It seems like most users are American so I don't want two separate tags to develop.

Comment: @Zxyrra ah.  Synonyms are more for things users wouldn't figure out on their own; a one-character spelling difference that occurs late in a word doesn't really need a synonym, because by the time someone has typed "beha" the tag will auto-complete and most people will recognize the word as just a different spelling.  We're a worldwide site; people should be used to variations like this.  Synonyms are more for completely different words that, if not synonymized, would end up as separate tags.